# Wordpress custom shortcode in page content not recognised by Yoast SEO plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

We are currently building a website and have a bit of a hiccup. We use the Code Snippets WordPress plugin to use a basic PHP code as a shortcode. The PHP grabs the current page title and outputs the first word of the page title, so if the page title is "London Fairy Rides" including the shortcode in the text will output "London" please see the code below:

```
function location_from_title( ){
  $page_title_var = explode(" ", get_the_title());
  return $page_title_var[0];
}
add_shortcode( 'location', 'location_from_title' );
```

Now the problem is, Yoast SEO plugin does not seem to recognise words generated with this method in it's page analysis or the preview snippet as keywords and seems to ignore them (for example if the keyword is "London Fairy Rides" and it is included in the page body like so ( [location] Fairy Rides ) the Yoast SEO does not recognise it. Disabling the Code Snippets plugin and including the php in functions.php yields the same result.
Are we doing something wrong, is the issue with the plugin, our code, or something else?

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. The pages are built with Elementor plugin.

Technical info

```
WordPress version: 4.7.5
Yoast SEO version: 4.8
```

Comment: Yoast doesn't parse short codes before running the analysis. There's a filter called `wpseo_pre_analysis_post_content` in Yoast which allows you to manually run short codes if you wish to.

Comment: Additional to the above comment, Yoast at one point (v 1.4.14) did run analysis on short codes, but it broke a bunch of stuff so it got reverted a few versions later.

Comment: @naththedeveloper, unless they brought it back that hook was deprecated years ago. https://developer.yoast.com/blog/yoast-seo-breaking-api-changes/